# ExecTask or (Insert)Task, whats the difference?

Tags: phing

Can someone explain the use of using all the different tasks instead of using simply `<exec/>`?

The PHPunit task is giving me alot of problems at the moment for example, why bother and not go for a simple `<exec/>` ?

Cant seem to find anything in the docs at all.

The docs are f.e. very confusing giving examples such as:

https://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/ch04s02.html (4.2 Writing A Simple Buildfile)

```
<target name="build" depends="prepare">
    <echo msg="Copying files to build directory..." />

    <echo msg="Copying ./about.php to ./build directory..." />
    <copy file="./about.php" tofile="./build/about.php" />

    <echo msg="Copying ./browsers.php to ./build directory..." />
    <copy file="./browsers.php" tofile="./build/browsers.php" />

    <echo msg="Copying ./contact.php to ./build directory..." />
    <copy file="./contact.php" tofile="./build/contact.php" />
</target>
```

The `copy` task has a `description` property, you would think that this would be somehow seem logical to interpret by summary reporters or something, instead of having a `echo` on top of every task..

Whats the best practise?

Answer (score 0):

Phing's [Copy Task](https://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/CopyTask.html) does not have a description property...

...other than that, if expressing an action is more concise and less error-prone when written as a [custom] task than as an unwieldy exec task I usually take that as a hint to go looking and/or write that custom task.

Sometimes going a little further and submitting a pull-request ;-)

[image]